# angularjs-dropdown-multiselect directive throwing an error element.html is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I using **angularjs-dropdown-multiselect** directive but it throwing an error like below.

**TypeError: element.html is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.template (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js:55)**

How to resolve that issue?

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

    <div ng-repeat="item in Items" >
    <div   class="row item-container">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <input ng-model="item.menu" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div  ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" 
                     options="options"  selected-model="selectedOptions" checkboxes="true"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"  >  
           <input type="text"  ng-model="item.date" mydatepicker />    
        </div>

    </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

**script**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
    app.controller('myController',function($scope){
     $scope.options = [];
      $scope.selectedOptions = [];  
        $scope.dropdownSetting = {
            scrollable: true,
            scrollableHeight: '200px'
        }
});
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Why dont you use ng-options since its just a dropdown!

Comment: Please make a fiddle for this issue, it helps to understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

<div ng-repeat="item in Items" >
<div   class="row item-container">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <input ng-model="item.menu" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div  multiple ng-options=""  ng-model="selectedOptions" checkboxes="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"  >  
       <input type="text"  ng-model="item.date" mydatepicker />    
    </div>

</div>
```